# irregular LDPC code construction algorithm

Tags: it.information-theory, random-matrices, coding-theory, random-permutations

I want to construct a sparse random binary matrix  ${{\bf{H}}_{m \times n}}$  that has the following properties

1-  Faction of columns of  weight  $i$ is  ${v_i}$ .

2-  Fraction of rows of weight $i$  is ${h_i}$.

3-  No two columns in the matrix have an overlap greater than one.

For instance, for ${v_2} = 7/10,{v_3} = 3/10$  and  ${h_4} = 2/5,{h_5} = 3/5$ the random binary matrix    can be represented as

${{\bf{H}}_{5 \times 10}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1
\end{array}} \right]$

The matrix  ${\bf{H}}$ is called irregular low density parity check matrix in channel coding. There are a few algorithms that have been proposed to construct the matrix for low to moderate dimension (maximum n=10e4,m=n/2) such as progressive edge growth (PEG). How can I construct   ${\bf{H}}$ for given ${v_i}$  and ${h_i}$  and the constraint 3 randomly for large dimension ( for example n=10e5,m=n/2)?

Comment: I think your matrix has $h_3 = 1$ at the moment.

Comment: Do you need the fractions to come out exactly right or will an approximation suffice? Similarly, do you need to sample exactly uniformly from the space of all possibilities or will approximately uniformly suffice?

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't need to satisfy the fractions exactly. In other words, we should be able to find large enough m and n to satisfy the fractions for a desired small error. The samples can be approximately uniformly random.

Comment: how "dense" are your constraints. What do you typically expect the following ratios to be? $$\frac{\mathrm{Number~~ of~~ v_i\neq 0}}{n}$$ and $$\frac{\mathrm{Number~~ of~~ h_i\neq 0}}{m}$$